# Evaluating integral using Riemann sums

Tags: r, math, statistics, simulation, numerical-integration

How to evaluate J=P(0<=Z<=1), where Z~N(0,1) using Riemann sums?

so J is the integral from 0 to 1 of the function (1/sqrt(2*pi))*exp^((-x^2)/2)

Here is my approach to implement this in R

```
 m<-5000
a<-0
b<-1
w<-(b-a)/m
x<-seq(a+(w/2),b-(w/2),w)
h<-(1/sqrt(2*pi))*exp^((-x^2)/2)

# Error in exp^((-x^2)/2) : non-numeric argument to binary operator

sum(h*w)
#Error: object 'h' not found
```

I don't know why marks such error, I type `is.numeric(x)` and returns `TRUE` so where the problem is exactly if I am combining numerics only?

Comment: what is ``exp``? I think ``exp`` is causing the problem.

Comment: @JimO. The exponential function

Comment: see my answer below.

Comment: Typos should just be closed.

Comment: @42- Ooh :( ok. I'd also like to know if my solution implemented is correct

Comment: Also not on-topic hear. That's more a methods question and either the math forum or the code review forum would be more appropriate. The only thing on-topic was the syntactic error of putting `^` immediately after "exp" and thinking that R would interpret that as e raised to a power. That was what I considered equivalent to a typo. It was the symbol "exp" that was not numeric. There is a function `exp` but you would have needed to use parentheses rather than the caret-character.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove `^` that follows `exp` function. Try:

```
m<-5000
a<-0
b<-1
w<-(b-a)/m
x<-seq(a+(w/2),b-(w/2),w)
h<-(1/sqrt(2*pi))*exp((-x^2)/2)

sum(h*w)
[1] 0.3413447
```

Comment: Thanks. what a mistake i did..

Comment: Is my solution implemented correctly btw ?

Comment: That, I do not know.

Comment: @Isa Yes, .34 looks about right. There is famous 68-95-99.7 rule(https://www.statisticshowto.datasciencecentral.com/68-95-99-7-rule/), which says that integral for gaussian distribution from -one sigma to +one sigma should be .68 (68%). Because you evaluate only positive part of distribution, you should get half of 68%, i.e..34

Comment: @Isa You could check it with easy: pnorm(1) - pnorm(0)
[1] 0.3413447

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux oh ok,yes it's fine also since I got `.3989423` using a different method: Monte Carlo for the integral. just `.05` of difference :)

Comment: @Isa That's a fairly large error on the Monte Carlo approach, since 0.399 corresponds to the integral from 0 to ~1.275 rather than 0 to 1.  I'm guessing you either have a bug in your Monte Carlo implementation or you need to boost your sample size.  The good news is that you should be able to estimate the precision of your answer using a confidence interval.

Comment: Followup - using the average height Monte Carlo method I get results that agree with the theoretical answer with a margin of error < 0.001 using a sample size of 10000.